# Android save and share Image From SDCard

Tags: android

Hi I'm Trying to save a drawable as a bitmap to the SDCard and then share it using a share intent. but the problem i'm having is that its just not sharing the image does anyone know how to do this or where im going wrong?

heres what i have tried so far

```
getHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            saveBitmapToExternalStorage(this, imageResourceFor Drawable, imageName);
                            File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/myfolder/"+ kitImagePath+".png");
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Subtitle");
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);  //optional//use this when you want to send an image
                            shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
                        }

                    });

 public static void saveBitmapToExternalStorage(Context context, int imageResource, String imageName){

        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),imageResource);

        //generate file
        File dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myfolder");
        File f = new File(dir, String.format(imageName + ".png"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);  
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            bos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you force `/sdcard/...`? Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfolder"`, instead, as you do when you save your image.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Bitmap use its URI to share.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Subtitle");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ kitImagePath+".png"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);  //optional//use this when you want to send an image
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Also as +Der Golem said. use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` to get External storage path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```